# opening links when I receive firebase notification

Tags: ios

Send a notification with firebase  if the application is in the background I receive the notification and open the link with the following code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary
    if let title = (aps?.value(forKey: "alert") as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "title"){
        var get_data = String()
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "titleList") != nil{
            get_data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "titleList") as! String
        }
        if get_data != ""{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(get_data+" ,"+(title as! String), forKey: "titleList")
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.set((title as! String), forKey: "titleList")
        }
    }
    if let body = (aps?.value(forKey: "alert") as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "body"){
        var get_data = String()
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "bodyList") != nil{
            get_data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "bodyList") as! String
        }
        if get_data != ""{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(get_data+" ,"+(body as! String), forKey: "bodyList")
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.set((body as! String), forKey: "bodyList")
        }
    }

    if let url = aps?.value(forKey: "url") as? String{
        print("get url:", url)
        var get_data = String()
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "urlList") != nil{
            get_data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "urlList") as! String
        }
        if get_data != ""{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(get_data+" ,"+url, forKey: "urlList")
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "urlList")
        }
        if url != ""{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "subPage"), object: nil, userInfo: ["url":url])

        }

    }
}
```

I would like to get the same thing if the application is killed

Comment: If your application is terminated, when user taps on the notification, app will be launched and notification data is passed to app in `launchOptions` of `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with in `applicationWillTerminate` in appdelegate,this method is called when the app is killed.

Comment: dove lo inserisco?

Comment: where do I insert it?

Comment: insert the same code in applicationWillTerminate method in appdelegate

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, applicationWillTerminate data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary
    if let title = (aps?.value(forKey: "alert") as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "title"){
        var get_data = String()
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "titleList") != nil{
            get_data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "titleList") as! String.......

Comment: you want to call this function when the app is killed right? if yes then this function will call when the app is killed

Comment: THANK YOU, I TRY